# Windows Phone 8: In app purchase screen not showing

Tags: windows-phone-8, in-app-purchase

I'm trying to add in-app purchase functionality to my game made with Unity3D in C#. To my knowledge when a user initiates a purchase - that is clicks say a 'buy' button from within your game they should be taken to a purchase screen?

Without going into the details of how plugins work, this is the function being called from the phone to initiate the purhase:

```
private static async Task<string>PurchaseUpgrade(string ID)
{
    var listings = await CurrentApp.LoadListingInformationAsync();

    var purchaseItem = listings.ProductListings.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value.ProductId == ID &&
                                                                x.Value.ProductType == ProductType.Durable);
    try
    {
        if (CurrentApp.LicenseInformation.ProductLicenses[purchaseItem.Value.ProductId].IsActive)
        {
            return false.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            Receipt = await CurrentApp.RequestProductPurchaseAsync(purchaseItem.Value.ProductId, true);
            return true.ToString();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception w)
    {
        return w.ToString();
    }
}
```

This gets called when the user clicks a 'buy' button from within unityplayer.

This is the first time I've worked with IAP so to my knowledge when the else block is entered which contains the line:

```
Receipt = await CurrentApp
              .RequestProductPurchaseAsync(purchaseItem.Value.ProductId, true);
```

It should 'bring up' a purchase screen? To confirm the purchase?

Anyway this is not the case, anyone got any experience with this?

Comment: What happens when you call RequestProductPurchaseAsync method? Is your App already published to Store. The code will work only on apps directly downloaded from store, not on debug versions. If the app is not published yet, you should use [CurrentAppSimulator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.store.currentappsimulator) for testing. [Here](http://invokeit.wordpress.com/2012/09/14/in-app-purchase-with-win8dev-winrt/) is a good example.

Comment: You cannot test your in-app purchase (other than using CurrentAppSimulator) if your app's ProductId (found in WPManifest.xml) and the ApplicationId (found in Dev Center) are not the same. Make it the same and it should work.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I'm actually using the MockAPI library provided from Msdn to test the purchases at the minute.

Answer (score 0):

This guide will help you test IAP in local machine Local IIS Web Service and WP8 Emulator

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj681689(v=vs.105).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj681689%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I would say you have to run this on UI thread

```
Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => ShowBuyDialog(productId));
```